# CSS прижать блок к низу родителя

Tags: html, css

есть конструкция:

```
<div id='header'>
   <div id='main_info'>
      <div>
       вывод информации
      </div>
      <ul>
       часть навигации
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id='sub_info'>
      <div>
      еще информация
      </div>
      <ul>
      еще часть навигации
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

навигация - горизонтальный список, уже приведен в нормальный вид.

как сделать так, чтоб блоки main_info и sub_info были одинаковыми по высоте(выравнивались по макс высоте), и элементы навигации были прибиты к низу родительских блоков?(были в одну линию)

предвижу вопросы "зачем такое размещение?" по условиям заказчика, в sub_info в зависимости от прав пользователя будут разные свистоперделки, от такой конструкции до картинки/формы/тупого текста...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы гарантированно прибить блоки к низу родителей, рекомендую использовать `position`:

```
#main_info, #sub_info {
  position: relative;
}
#main_info ul, #sub_info ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

вот только списки при этом выпадут из потока, Вам придется под них создавать отступы внутри родителей (`padding-bottom` = высота `ul`).

На счет равенства по высоте в голову приходит только эмуляция таблицы: `display` `table-row` и `table-cell` (должно прокатить, см. в спецификации CSS).